# How to draw the graph in double line using canvas.js?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
  var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
   title: {
    text: "Line Chart"
   },
   axisX: {
    interval: 10
   },
   data: [{
    type: "line",
    dataPoints: [
      { x: 10, y: 35 },
      { x: 20, y: 14 },
      { x: 30, y: 20 },
      { x: 40, y: 60 },
      { x: 50, y: 50 },
      { x: 60, y: 80 },
      { x: 70, y: 40 },
      { x: 80, y: 60 },
      { x: 90, y: 10 },
      { x: 100, y: 50 },
      { x: 110, y: 40 },
      { x: 120, y: 14 },
      { x: 130, y: 70 },
      { x: 140, y: 40 },
      { x: 150, y: 90 },
    ]
   }]
  });
  chart.render();
 }
 
 </script>
 
</head>
<body>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 400px; width: 100%;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have some code in canvas.js but i want to draw the graph in double time graph in based on equation for example 5x+6y=0;8x+5y=0 the equation type in input to draw the graph.  i added one example model graph based on the example model graph how to programming the canvas.js please help me.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>  
 <script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function () {
   var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
    title: {
     text: "Basic Spline Chart"
    },
  data: [
      {        
        type: "spline",
        dataPoints: [
        { x: 10, y: 10 },
        { x: 20, y: 25},
        { x: 30, y: 20 },
        { x: 40, y: 25 },
        { x: 50, y: 27 },
        { x: 60, y: 28 },
        { x: 70, y: 28 },
        { x: 80, y: -24 },
        { x: 90, y: 26}
      
        ]
      },
        {        
        type: "spline",
        dataPoints: [
        { x: 10, y: 71 },
        { x: 20, y: 55},
        { x: 30, y: 50 },
        { x: 40, y: 65 },
        { x: 50, y: 95 },
        { x: 60, y: 68 },
        { x: 70, y: 28 },
        { x: 80, y: 34 },
        { x: 90, y: 14}
      
        ]
      }
      ]
   
   });
   chart.render();
  }
 </script>
 
 
</head>

<body>
 <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 400px; width: 100%;"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

I my question how to draw the graph in double line using canvas.js?
Ans: only add the array function in my question to plot the graph based on array points.